# tSQL Sum union query with different outputs per year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

So I looked around the site and found similar questions with answers that helped me get to this point, but nothing that addresses my problem. The actual query has a 5 different Unions but i'm only showing 2 here for simplicity's sake:

```
SELECT 
    'Natural Gas (Stationary)' AS GHGType, 
    Year,
    ROUND(SUM(CO2), 0) AS CO2, 
    ROUND(SUM(CH4), 0) AS CH4, 
    ROUND(SUM(N2O), 0) AS N2O, 
    ROUND(SUM(TotalCO2e), 0) AS TotalCO2e, 
    ROUND(SUM(TotalCO2eMetric), 0) AS TotalCO2eMetric, 
    1 AS zOrder
FROM
    vw_NaturalGas
WHERE        
     CO2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
     Year

UNION

SELECT 
    'Mobile (Fleet)' AS GHGType, 
    Year, 
    ROUND(SUM(CO2), 0) AS CO2, 
    ROUND(SUM(CH4), 0) AS CH4, 
    ROUND(SUM(N2O), 0) AS N2O, 
    ROUND(SUM(TotalCO2e), 0) AS TotalCO2e,
    ROUND(SUM(TotalCO2eMetric), 0) AS TotalCO2eMetric, 
    2 AS zOrder
FROM 
    vw_MobileData
WHERE 
    CO2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    Year
```

This returns the following output:

```
|GHGType                 |Year|CO2|CH4|N2O|TotalCO2e|TotalCO2eMetric|
+------------------------+----+---+---+---+---------+---------------+
|Natural Gas (Stationary)|2016|12 |14 |61 |3465     |126            |
|Natural Gas (Stationary)|2017|22 |24 |43 |10       |1204           |
|Mobile (Fleet)          |2016|5  |17 |23 |31       |832            |
|Mobile (Fleet)          |2017|25 |57 |73 |11       |713            |
```

What I need is a new GHGType (scope 1) that sums the Natural Gas and Mobile fields for each year (so there will be a Scope 1 for 2016 and 2017):

```
|GHGType                 |Year|CO2|CH4|N2O|TotalCO2e|TotalCO2eMetric|
+------------------------+----+---+---+---+---------+---------------+
|Natural Gas (Stationary)|2016|12 |14 |61 |3465     |126            |
|Natural Gas (Stationary)|2017|22 |24 |43 |10       |1204           |
|Mobile (Fleet)          |2016|5  |17 |23 |31       |832            |
|Mobile (Fleet)          |2017|25 |57 |73 |11       |713            |
|Scope 1                 |2016|17 |21 |84 |3496     |958            |
|Scope 1                 |2017|47 |38 |117|21       |1917           |
```

I tried to do this using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    'Scope 1' AS GHGType, 
    Year, 
    SUM(Scope1.CO2), 
    SUM(Scope1.CH4), 
    SUM(Scope1.N2O), 
    SUM(Scope1.TotalCO2e), 
    SUM(Scope1.TotalCO2eMetric), 
    5 as zOrder 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        'Natural Gas (Stationary)' AS GHGType, 
        Year,
        ROUND(SUM(CO2), 0) AS CO2, 
        ROUND(SUM(CH4), 0) AS CH4, 
        ROUND(SUM(N2O), 0) AS N2O, 
        ROUND(SUM(TotalCO2e), 0) AS TotalCO2e, 
        ROUND(SUM(TotalCO2eMetric), 0) AS TotalCO2eMetric, 
        1 AS zOrder
    FROM
        vw_NaturalGas
    WHERE        
         CO2 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
         Year

    UNION

    SELECT 
        'Mobile (Fleet)' AS GHGType, 
        Year, 
        ROUND(SUM(CO2), 0) AS CO2, 
        ROUND(SUM(CH4), 0) AS CH4, 
        ROUND(SUM(N2O), 0) AS N2O, 
        ROUND(SUM(TotalCO2e), 0) AS TotalCO2e,
        ROUND(SUM(TotalCO2eMetric), 0) AS TotalCO2eMetric, 
        2 AS zOrder
    FROM 
        vw_MobileData
    WHERE 
        CO2 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        Year) Scope1 
GROUP BY 
    GHGType, Year, zorder
```

But instead of summing the columns, it just duplicates them with the GHGType Scope 1. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find this easier if you union the data first and then use `grouping sets`:

```
select coalesce(GHGType, 'Scope') as GhGType, Year,
       sum(CO2) as CO2, . . .
from ((select 'Natural Gas (Stationary)' AS GHGType, Year, CO2, CH4, N20,
              TotalCO2e, TotalCO2eMetric, 1 AS zOrder
       from vw_NaturalGas
       where CO2 is not null
      ) union all
      (select 'Mobile (Fleet)' AS GHGType, Year, CO2, CH4, N20,
              TotalCO2e, TotalCO2eMetric, 1 AS zOrder
       from vw_NaturalGas
       where CO2 is not null
      ) union all
      . . .
     ) v
group by grouping sets ( (GHGType, Year), (Year) )
order by zorder, year;
```

Comment: this just created a table with duplicated Scope 1's that have null years

Comment: @DBA108642 . . . I misunderstood what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would just dump your select data into a temp table and sum the columns after it's all been aggregated, it should make your data a little easier to work from.

```
create table #tempTable
(
    GHGType varchar(50),
    Year int,
    CO2 int,
    ....etc..
)

insert into #tempTable (GHGType, Year, CO2)
SELECT 
    'Natural Gas (Stationary)' AS GHGType, 
    Year,
    ROUND(SUM(CO2), 0) AS CO2, 
    ROUND(SUM(CH4), 0) AS CH4, 
    ROUND(SUM(N2O), 0) AS N2O, 
    ROUND(SUM(TotalCO2e), 0) AS TotalCO2e, 
    ROUND(SUM(TotalCO2eMetric), 0) AS TotalCO2eMetric, 
    1 AS zOrder
into #tempTable
FROM
    vw_NaturalGas
WHERE        
     CO2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
     Year
```

Then it should be as easy as inserting the data based on a query of the #tempTable. If i understand what you're trying to do this is how i would do it.

```
insert into #tempTable(GHGType, Year, CO2, ... etc..)
select 'Scope 1', 2016, sum(CO2), ...etc..
from #tempTable
where Year = 2016

select * from #tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     'Natural Gas (Stationary)' + 'Mobile (Fleet)' AS GHGType
    ,temp.Year
    ,SUM(temp.CO2) AS CO2
    ,SUM(temp.CH4) AS CH4
    ,SUM(temp.N2O) AS N2O
    ,SUM(temp.TotalCO2e) AS TotalCO2e
    ,SUM(temp.TotalCO2eMetric) AS TotalCO2eMetric
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
         'Natural Gas (Stationary)' AS GHGType
        , Year
        , round(sum(CO2), 0) AS CO2
        , round(sum(CH4), 0) AS CH4
        , round(sum(N2O), 0) AS N2O
        , round(sum(TotalCO2e), 0) AS TotalCO2e
        , round(sum(TotalCO2eMetric), 0) AS TotalCO2eMetric
        , 1 AS zOrder
   FROM            
       vw_NaturalGas
   WHERE        
       CO2 IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY Year

   UNION

   SELECT 
        'Mobile (Fleet)' AS GHGType
        , Year
        , round(sum(CO2), 0) AS CO2
        , round(sum(CH4), 0) AS CH4
        , round(sum(N2O), 0) AS N2O
        , round(sum(TotalCO2e), 0) AS TotalCO2e
        , round(sum(TotalCO2eMetric), 0) AS TotalCO2eMetric
        , 2 AS zOrder
   FROM 
        vw_MobileData
   WHERE 
       CO2 IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY Year
  )
  AS temp
GROUP BY 
  temp.Year
```